# What does "Exception in thread \"main\" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" mean when executing java .class file?

Tags: java, android, gradle

Java and Gradle beginner's question.
I made a project directory for java and gradle test:

#### The directory hierarchy :

[image]

#### HelloWorld.java:

```
package foo.bar;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, world");
    }
}
```

#### build.gradle:

`apply plugin:'java'`

#### Then,`gradle build` this project and generated what i need.

[image]

### As you see above, my problem is why doesn't this execute correctly? Even through I `cd` to .class path.

[image]

======================================================================

#### While, if I remove `package foo.bar;` in HelloWorld.java, and repeat gradle commands and execute at `he.bak` directory then the error remained the same.

#### But when I `cd` to the directory where `HelloWorld.java` placed. everything goes OK！Why? something related with CLASSPATH environment variables or other causes?

[image]

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
UPDATE
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Thought you guys' warm replies, I know that I should combine the CLASSPATH and the period-separated executable .class file to figure out what's going on when executing java class file.
I experiment my thought resulting in 2 point to this question:

1. The -cp option path parameter `A/B` plus the executable file `c.d.e.class` finally form the `A/B/c.d.e.class` full path where the class is actually located.
2. If I specify the package in source code file with `package d`,I must split the full path in the form of `java -cp A/B/c/d  e.class`. split in other ways all will result in errors.

**something I am not sure here is** :

When I specify my package path in my source code file, It determined the only classpath when executing corresponding executable, right?
If it is the truth, How does a project with lots of package and sources files work?
What's the root principle?

Comment: Android Studio is using Gradle.

Comment: packages are usually associated to folders.

Answer (score 2):

When in `build/classes/main` try `java foo.bar.HelloWorld` instead of `java HelloWorld`

The reason you need to specify `foo.bar.HelloWorld` is because you specified `package foo.bar;`. This tells java that the class should be in `foo/bar/HelloWorld` and the fully qualified name for HelloWorld is `foo.bar.HelloWorld`. If you want to execute the class from a different working directory however, you can specify the classpath explicitly using the `-cp` option, e.g., `java -cp c:\myproject\build\classes\main foo.bar.HelloWorld`.

By the way, the classpath default is the current working directory (i.e., `.`) but `java -cp c:\myproject\build\classes\main foo.bar.HelloWorld` will NOT have the classpath set to the current working directory if it is explicitly set using the `-cp` option. If you want to include the current working directory but explicitly set it, or even add more directories, you can chain them using semicolons like this: `java -cp .;c:\myproject\build\classes\main foo.bar.HelloWorld`. So this will include both the current working directory and the directory I specified.

Comment: can you tell why this can be OK, and executing at other path result in error

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but some more question remained, I have edited the question below UPDATE line!